# jQuery .on keyup and blur firing onload only

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

Problem:
The `blur` and `keyup` events each fire once onload, and only onload. How can I get them to work correctly?

jQuery:

```
function myFunction(text){
    alert(text);
}
$('#input1').on({
    keyup: myFunction('keyup'),
    blur: myFunction('blur'),
    focus: function(){console.log('focus!');}
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/GrMQX/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not assigning a function to `keyup` and `blur`, you're assigning the result of the execution of `myFunction`.

Change it like this:

```
$('#input1').on({
    keyup: function() { myFunction('keyup'); },
    blur:  function() { myFunction('blur'); },
    focus: function() { console.log('focus!'); }
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/GrMQX/5/)

Comment: Do I really have to have an anonymous function first?

Comment: No, but it's the easiest way in this case.

Answer (score 6):

You're not declaring the functions as callbacks, you're executing them and their return result is assigned as a callback (which doens't work).

Try this:

```
  $('#input1').on({
    keyup: function() { myFunction('keyup') },
    blur: function() { myFunction('blur') },
    focus: function(){console.log('focus!');}
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass a function as an argument.. you are passing the return value of the called function

```
function myFunction(text){
    alert(text);
}
$('#input1').on({
    keyup: function(){myFunction('keyup');},
    blur: function(){myFunction('blur');},
    focus: function(){console.log('focus!');}
});
```

---

Or you can convert your `myFunction` to a function generator

```
function myFunction(text){
   return function(){
       console.log(text);
   }
}

$('#input1').on({
    keyup: myFunction('keyup'),
    blur: myFunction('blur'),
    focus: function(){console.log('focus!');}
});
```

**Demo at** https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/GrMQX/6/

Comment: Is returning the function going to be slower than calling the anonymous function?

Comment: there is a negligible overhead once when you bind the event handlers.. after that the actual event handling is exactly the same.  But it solves the issue of passing a parameter when binding .. (*and not repeating the body function for each event you want to handle..*)

Answer (score 4):

You're actually executing the functions when you call them that way. Try this:

```
$('#input1').on({
    keyup: function(){myFunction('keyup')},
    blur: function(){myFunction('blur')},
    focus: function(){console.log('focus!');}
});
```

**[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/GrMQX/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

use with .on() Event

```
$(document).on("keyup blur", "#input1", function(event)
    {       
    // your code        

    });
```